# How to remove the effect due to camera shake from a video using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, camera, computer-vision

I have a video of moving parts taken using a static camera. I wish to track & analyze the co-ordinates of various parts in the video. But the co-ordinates values are affected by camera movement. How do I calibrate the camera shake? I don't have any static point in the video (except for the top&bottom edges of video).

All I wish to get is the co-ordinates of (centroids, may be) moving parts adjusted for camera shake. I use MATLAB's computer vision toolbox to process the video.

Comment: Frame-by-frame correlation?  Some kind of feature detection (e.g. Canny edge detection) which you can use to line the frames up?

Comment: this depends on ALOT of factors that you didn't include in your question.  What is the video capturing?  Is the camera in a stationary location or moving around?  Define "noise".  Are you referring to blurring?  Something not in a stationary part of the frame?

Comment: @JimClay: The objects in the movie are moving relative to each other, so I can't take feature as reference feature.

Comment: Try searching for "motion compensation" and you'll find a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I've worked on super-resolution algorithms in the past, and as a side affect, I got image stabilization using [phase correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation). It's very resilient to noise, and it's quite fast. You should be able to achieve sub-pixel accuracy using a weighted centroid around the peak location, or some kind of peak-fitting routine. Running phase correlation on successive frames will tell you the translational shift that occurs frame-to-frame. You can use an [affine warp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) to remove the shift.

A similar, but slower, approach is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html?searchHighlight=cross%20correlation&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) this example is using [Normalized Cross Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_correlation).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Matlab 2013a or later then video stabilization can be done using point matching [Point Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-stabilization-using-point-feature-matching.html) or by [Template Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-stabilization.html). I guess they're available in Matlab 2012b but I haven't tested it out.